# Firefox size rendering vs other browser

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, browser

Please see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3qzb7q0d/)

HTML:

```
<body>
<header>
    <div id="top-header">
        <div id="search-div">
            <form method="get" name="search">
                <input value="Search" id="search-button" type="submit">

                <input name="term" id="search-box" type="search">

                <div id="search-options">
                    <ul>
                        <li id="search-option-icon">0</li>
                        <li>1</li>
                        <li>2</li>
                        <li>3</li>
                        <li>4</li>
                        <li>5</li>
                    </ul>
                    <input name="search-type" id="search-type" type="hidden">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="bottom-header">something here</div>
</header>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-size:100%;
   border:0 none;
}

body{
    direction: rtl;
}

header{
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height: 80px;
}


/*
--------------------------------------------------------
|   header
--------------------------------------------------------
*/
header > div{
    width: 100%;
    position:relative;
    position: relative;
}

#top-header{
    background: #9600ee;
    height: 52px;
}

#bottom-header{
    background: white;
    height: 29px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
    box-shadow:0 1px 1px #e0e0e0;
}

#img-logo{
    display: inline-block;
}

/*
--------------------------------------------------------
|   header > search-div
--------------------------------------------------------
*/
#search-div{
    width:432px;
    position: absolute;
    top:8px;
    height: 36px;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin:auto;
    z-index: 3;
}

#search-options{
    height: 36px;
    width: 49px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    background: linear-gradient(#FFFFFF,#e6e6e6);
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
    left:0;
}

#search-options > ul > li{
    display: none;
}

#search-option-icon{
    display: block !important;
}

#search-options:hover > ul > li{
    width: 49px;
    background: red;
    display: block;
}

#search-box{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 36px;
    width: 325px;
    right:49px;
    padding:0 5px;
    border-right:1px solid #9600ee;
    border-left: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
}

#search-button{
    height: 100%;
    width: 48px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    background: linear-gradient(#FFFFFF,#e6e6e6);
    border-radius: 0 2px 2px 0;
}
```

I am going to create a page that its direction is Right to Left. I don't know why Firefox is showing a different result then other browsers?

**What I see in Chrome:**
[image]

**What Firefox shows(Firefox 37):**
[image]

What is the problem? And why is Firefox (or my Firefox) showing a different result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input elements are rendered depending on the browsers and OS with a different appearance. Chrome seems to apply `box-sizing: border-box;` to an input element as soon as you change the `type` to `search`, but Firefox doesn't do that (currently I would say that Firefox is right about that but I need to check this in the specs).

Firefox does not change the `box-sizing` for those elements and because the default `box-sizing`  is `content-box`,  the complete *outer-width* is `width` + `padding` + `border` (for more details you can look here [CSS-Tricks: Box Sizing](https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/)). As of that your `#search-box` in Firefox does not have an *outer-width* of `325px`.

If you want to have better control about the *outer-width* of the elements you need to use `border-box` for `box-sizing`. You can change the `box-sizing`  for your whole page using :

```
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
   box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

Code from site: [Paul Irish: * { Box-sizing: Border-box } FTW](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/)

Updated <kbd>**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3qzb7q0d/2/)**</kbd> using `border-box`.

Comment: I did not know that!

Answer (score 1):

Your #search-div is too narrow, making the elements crammed together. Your search divs are also out of order. I would suggest arranging them in the order of search-options, search-box, search-button, then adding float: left; to each of their styles as well as some margin-left: 20px; so they aren't right next to each other.

Your search-box also has a small width cutting off letters.

See this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3qzb7q0d/1/

Something like:

```
#search-options {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
  // whatever else
}
```

Add that to each search portion.

Increase the width of #search-button

Remove the width from #search-div

Comment: Oh, of course I know that, I say why Firefox is different with other browser! PX is PX and it shouldn't be different

Comment: For some reason, firefox is making #search-box 17px wider than in chrome causing the form to be wider than its containing div, but I'm not sure why. However, you can marginalize problems like this by writing proper markup and stylings.

Comment: Thanks, But I need to know reasons!